# Why should we use cross_val_predict instead of just normally predicting our instances using all the training set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Aren't we using less data to train our model when we are using [cross_val_predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)? Say I have the following code;

```
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_pred_fullData = sgd_clf.predict(X_train)

y_train_pred_cv = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
```

Based on my understanding how `cross_val_predict` works (with `cv=3`) is that it divides the training set into three equal chunks and it trains on the 2nd and 3rd chunk to predict the labels of instances in the 1st one third of the instances in the training set, and uses the 1st and 3rd chunk to predict the labels of the 2nd one third of the instances, and lastly it uses the 1st and 2nd one third of the training data to predict the labels of the 3rd chunk. Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Given the above, wouldn't it be better for me to use `y_train_pred_fullData` rather than `y_train_pred_cv` because I am using more data to train my model to make predictions?

If I would prefer `y_train_pred_fullData` over `y_trian_pred_cv` under the conditions of using more data to train on, under what conditions would I choose to use `y_train_pred_cv`?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we don't use `cross_val_predict` for that. You use cross validation to compare performance of different estimators and select the best one. You then fit the best estimator on the full data.
Default options for model comparison are `cross_validate` (when you have multiple metrics to check) and `cross_val_score` (when you have only one metric).

For usages of `cross_val_predict`, the documentation [states](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation):

> **The function cross_val_predict is appropriate for**:
>
> Visualization of predictions obtained from different models.
>
> Model blending: When predictions of one supervised estimator are used
> to train another estimator in ensemble methods.